# How can Class<T> be generic?

Tags: java, class, generics

The Java class `Class<T>` being Generic is confusing because of following reasons.

Imagine a class `Cake<T>{}`
So you can create 
`new Cake<Pineapple>` and `new Cake<Apple>` etc
If each class e.x `Apple` has a parameterizable Class Object, and If class `Class` is generic, then it seems like a possibility to create `Apple<Something>` or `Integer<Something>`, which does not make any sense.

I dont know what i am perceiving wrongly here. It seems like inception, but a deeper level is the same level as above level.

Assume below generic Class

```
public class Cake<T> {
  T cakeType;

  void setCakeType(T cakeArg){
    this.cakeType = cakeArg;
  }

  void doStuff(){
    System.out.println(cakeType.toString());
  }
}
```

Assume Pineapple is the non generic class as Parameter type for Cake

```
public class Pineapple {

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "I am a Pineapple";
  }
}
```

If class `Class` was not generic, then by intuition, there will be `Pineapple Class` object
But as class `Class<T>` itself is generic. Then it seems like a possibility to create parameterizable class object of `Pineapple` i.e `Pineapple<Something>`.

Base Assumption: There is only one `Class` Object for each class. What is the sense about parameterizing it ?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you include some code?

Comment: The `T` in `Class<T>` does not correspond to the `T` in `Cake<T>`. The former represents the compile-time type of the class itself; meaning `Pineapple.class` is an instance of `Class<Pineapple>`.

Comment: "If class Class is generic, then it seems like a possibility to create Apple<Something> or Integer<Something>"  it's not clear how you arrive at that possibility from where you started.

Comment: @pvg             I arrived at that possibility as follows. If Class of Class wasnt generic. Then Pineapple would have just a Class Object i.e Pineapple.class. But Since Class Class<T> is generic, so Pineapple could have a Class object of <T> types. Kinda like, instead of Pineapple.class, we could have Pineapple<Something1>.class, Pineapple<Something2>.class

Comment: A specific Class<Pineapple> exists, as a specialization, for Pineapple. What I'm not following is how you get from that to 'there could be any kind of Class<whatever> for Pineapple. That doesn't seem clear at all.

Comment: @pvg            have means a Class Object exists for a Pineapple.

Comment: @pvg           Thanks for your explanation. I guess I was thinking of it in some weird manner, kinda like imagining a Snake eating its own tail.

Comment: You can very easily get there, it's not at all weird, once you start thinking about types and types-of-types and further down the rabbit hole. And that's why we're asking you these annoying and specific questions, it's so we can more easily explain where the language specification demands the snake stop eating its tail.

Comment: @ChetanGowda Love the imagery :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to tackle this from a few different approaches; I think there's a fundamental disconnect between what's happening, so a scattershot approach might have a better chance of one of the points making it all "click."

**The hierarchy**

So, firstly, don't think of Apple as *having* a Class object; rather, there is an Apple class, and, sitting next to it, a Class object which describes it. But that Class object just exists on its own, and is not part of Apple's hierarchy. It's not Apple's parent; it's its best friend.

The base class for all classes is Object, not Class. Now, if Object were parameterized, you'd have something along the lines of what you're describing -- but it's not. Since Class is not part of Apple's hierarchy, it does not logically follow that Class being parametrized makes Apple parameterized.

**By analogy to other generic classes**

The point of a Class object is to talk about other objects -- to tell us things like "this is a T," or "here's how you create a T." So, how does each instance tell us at compile-time which kind of things it's talking about? Via the parameter.

Similarly, the point of a List object is to talk about other objects -- to put them into a group together. And it also uses the generic parameter to describe the kinds of things it talks about. With a List, you can tell what's in it just by the type signature: a `List<String>` concerns Strings while a `List<Integer>` concerns Integers. Well, in just the same way, a `Class<String>` talks about Strings while a `Class<Integer>` talks about Integers. The fact that Class is parameterized has no more effect on String or Integer than does the fact that List is parameterized.

In other words: at the highest level, `List<String>` does things with Strings. So does a `Class<String>`

**Some use cases**

Finally, it may be helpful to think about *why* Class is parameterized. There are only a few methods on Class that return the `T` type. Let's take a look at two of them:

```
T newInstance()
T cast(Object o);
```

If Class were not parameterized, both of these would return Object. You'd have to do something like this:

```
Class<Apple> appleClass = ...;
Apple newApple = (Apple) appleClass.newInstance();
Apple existingApple = (Apple) appleClass.cast(existingObject);
```

Okay, as such that's not too bad. But in this case, we already knew the type of thing we were interested in (an Apple). That's why we could add the Apple casts, but by the same token, it's why using the `Class<Apple>` isn't useful. That snippet above would be better off just being done as:

```
Apple newApple = new Apple();
Apple existingApple = (Apple) existingObject;
```

Instead, the generic aspect of classes are most often useful when you're in a method that is itself generic. For instance:

```
<T> T tryConsume(Consumer<T> consumer, Object item, Class<T> consumeClass) {
  T itemCasted = consumeClass.cast(item);
  consumer.consume(itemCasted);
}
```

Granted, this example isn't very interesting. But the one thing I'll point out is that without the consumeClass, you would have to cast item to `(T)`. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this would actually be a no-op at runtime, and if the item were of the wrong class, the ClassCastException would come in from a weird, generated line within the `consumer` code -- not from within tryConsume, where it's nice and clear. To make that `cast` method actually *do* the cast, and do it usefully, you need `consumeClass.cast(item)` to return a `T`. And to do that, `consumeClass` has to be of type `Class<T>`.